# Why does Photoshop change the position of my PNG when creating a GIF?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, gif

I'm trying to create a GIF using PNGs I made in Illustrator. Each of them have the same position and size but when I export it to Photoshop, the image position changes per frame. How do I fix this?

Comment: How exactly are you importing the PNGs in to Photoshop?

Comment: Run `pngcheck -v file.png` and see if there are ancillary chunks such as "oFFs" in the file.  I don't know if Illustrator adds such chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Try bringing them into Photoshop this way:

Go to File > Scripts > Load Files into Stack:

[image: PS File Menu Path]

In that dialog choose 'Attempt to Automatically Align Source Images':

[image: Load Files into Stack Dialog]

That ought to get your layers all lined up for you...